# jQuery Validation not validating

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, jquery-validate

In my ASP.NET Web Application I'm trying to sending data from a User Control using jQuery Ajax call to WebMethod. So within the User Control I'm using HTML controls only.

Now I need to validate the input data before sending data with Ajax call. I tried using [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) but it does not work as Form validity is always `true`

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" class="text-box" />

<button type="button" id="btnSubmitInquiry" class="button" value="Submit">
    Submit
</button>
```

Javascript :

```
$('#btnSubmitInquiry').click(function () {

    $('#Form1').validate({
        rules: {
            txtName: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

    var inquiry = {};
    inquiry.Name = $('#txtName').val();
    //more fields

    var DTO = { 'inquiry': inquiry };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/Web/Site/AjaxHandler.aspx/Save',
        data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        } 

    });
});
```

How to make this work?

Comment: how about placing your AJAX call inside an `if` condition such as 

`if($('#txtName').val() != '' || $('#txtName').val() != null) {//ajax call}`

Comment: @harsha Yes that can be done but the problem with that is I need to validate required fields + emails + urls. so validating everything and prompting user will need to do manually (without using a plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add `if ($("#Form1").valid())` before Ajax call

```
    if ($("#Form1").valid()) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //....

        });
    }
```